# Node/bash/(fish) script to execute arguments unparsed in JS

Tags: node.js, bash, command-line-arguments, fish

I'm trying to write a node command that simply evaluates and outputs the code passed in the arguments. Ideally I wouldn't have to wrap them in quotes or put them in a file first. If the node/bash script is called `n` and is in the path, this is what I want to happen:

```
$ n 1 + "1"
11
```

I tried to achieve this by simply joining all the shell arguments with a space, but the case above fails, because the arguments are `["1", "+", "1"]` as the double quotes is part of the shell syntax to define an argument. This means that what I get instead is this:

```
$ n 1 + "1"
2
```

Here are my attempts in both node

```
#!/usr/bin/node
console.log(eval(process.argv.slice(2).join(' ')))
```

and bash

```
#!/bin/bash
node -e "console.log(eval(\"$*\"))"
```

I tried getting there from another angle later on: I knew `ps <pid>` stores the full command, and I thought it wouldn't parse it in any way. This was why I thought that it can't be impossible to do this without adding some weird internal hooks. So I wrote a node script to output the ps-stored command at the current pid:

```
#!/usr/bin/node
require('child_process').exec(`ps ${process.pid}`, (err, stdout) => {
  const [ headers, process ] = stdout.split('\n');
  const commandIndex = headers.indexOf('COMMAND');
  const command = process.substring(commandIndex).split(' ').slice(2).join(' ');
  console.log(command);
})
```

unfortunately, `ps` also stores a parsed input:

```
$ n 1 + "1"
1 + 1
```

I would have thought bash would have an environment variable with the unparsed current command, but I couldn't find it.

I'm actually using [fish](https://fishshell.com/) to actually run the command, which might give some advantage, but I realize that a question about fish might not be useful to as many people.

Maybe there is a way to get those arguments from within node? A hidden environment variable I might have missed? How would I go about creating an `$ n 1 + "1"` that distinguishes between quoted and unquoted arguments so that it outputs `11`?

Wrapping or escaping is not acceptable workaround!

Comment: `1` and `"1"` both produce the exact same words; the shell strips the quotes before passing the arguments to `n`. You are probably better off starting with a *single* quoted argument representing the entire expression, rather than having `n` piece together an expression from a number of arguments.

Comment: @chepnerI asked the question precisely because I wanted to avoid that

Comment: Why? It's a lot simpler to say "My script accepts an expression in the following format:...", then pass it as a single quoted string than to make your script depend on the particular semantics of whatever shell is used to call your script.

Answer (score 1):

> How would I go about creating an $ n 1 + "1" that distinguishes between quoted and unquoted arguments so that it outputs 11?

You don't. One of the fundamental ideas of shell script, which applies to fish as well as bash, is that the shell processes your arguments to then pass them to the program.

This applies not just to quotes (they are used so that e.g. `"file with spaces"` is passed as one argument, or so that `'$var'` does not do variable expansion), but also to `*` (which does globbing) and `$` (which does a bunch of expansions, depending on the shell).

And unless you specifically want to depend on a specific shell running your program (which you probably don't), there is no way to turn that off.

One possible workaround would be to use your tool as a REPL, so users would invoke `n`, and then type the expression.

Another is to expect the entire expression as one argument, so users can use

```
n '1 + "1"'
```

which you will receive as `1 + "1"`.

I also believe you're slightly overvaluing the problem. If you're using a shell, you need to generally perform this sort of escaping, and if your tool suddenly didn't have it it would actually be *more* confusing, not less.